# How to modify posts_where filter only for the search query

Tags: filters, posts-where, request-filter

I'm using posts_where filter in order to modify the user searches on a web, but i find out that some default widgets like the "more recent posts" uses this filter too and their behaviour are also modified. 
I am trying to find a way to avoid that anything other than the users searches use the posts_where filter.

This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where_statement' );

function posts_where_statement( $where ) {
   global $wp_query;
   global $expp;
   global $wpdb;
   $local_db = $wpdb->prefix."posts";
   $front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');

   if ( ('page' != get_option('show_on_front') || $front_page_id != $wp_query->query_vars['page_id']) && (!($wp_query->is_search)) )
       return $where;

   //some $where modifications

   remove_all_actions ( '__after_loop');
   return $where;
}
```

Is there any other function or a way to make this hook/filter only work with the search query? (the one that fetches the results from the user input)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem with your current snippet is that you are just checking the global main query object, no matter what the current query object is.

**Workaround:**

Note that the second input argument for the `posts_where` filter callback, is the current query object.

Use that to determine if it's the *main search query* on the front-end with:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where, \WP_Query $q ) 
{
    if( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_search()) // No global $wp_query here
    {
        // ... your modifications
    }

    return $where;      

}, 10, 2 ); // Note the priority 10 and number of input arguments is 2
```

There's also the [`posts_search`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d2a6ea340e7537f3b12c937eace66da8acea9201/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1997) filter for the WHERE search part, if that's what you need to modify.

But in general I would say only modify the generated SQL by hand if, you really must and have no other  alternatives.

Comment: +1 for type hinting. Not a fan of `$q` though.

Comment: thanks, It would be nice to have an interface. yes it's a valid point regarding the variable name. I must admit that the code scrollbars on this site, affects how I write answers - I try to avoid them ;-) Some use `$wp_query` but that could be confused with the global `$wp_query`, other use `$qry` or `$query`, but that might also be confusing when we're dealing with SQL query ;-) I settled for `$q` in this short snippet and it also looks simpler than e.g. `$wp_query_obj`.Usually I take the multiple if-contidtions into a seperate line @MichaelEcklund

Comment: what does  \WP_Query $q mean? I mean why the slash?

Comment: @brett If we use a [namespace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) in our plugin, then we need this for WordPress classes, as WordPress uses the global space.