# How to use the query hook/filter?

Tags: wp-query, filters, hooks, query

I want to stop this query from running:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_author IN (1)  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3`

Apparently https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/ can be tried for this. But if I try the following code in functions.php of the active theme:

`apply_filters( 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wpxt_posts.ID FROM wpxt_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wpxt_posts.post_author IN (1)  AND wpxt_posts.post_type = \'post\' AND (wpxt_posts.post_status = \'publish\')  ORDER BY wpxt_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3', string $query )` (escaping quotes)

or:

`apply_filters( 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wpxt_posts.ID FROM wpxt_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wpxt_posts.post_author IN (1)  AND wpxt_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wpxt_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wpxt_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3', string $query )`

There are errors. How should this be used in this case?

Edit: The 'duplicate' given does not explain how to use the https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/ function as this question is asking.

Comment: Why do you need to stop this particular query from running. Where is it running in the first place?

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/353155/stop-all-sql-calc-found-rows-wordpress-queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop all SQL\_CALC\_FOUND\_ROWS wordpress queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/353155/stop-all-sql-calc-found-rows-wordpress-queries)

Comment: I think you're looking for a [posts_where filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251839/how-to-modify-posts-where-filter-only-for-the-search-query :: work from there? https://macarthur.me/posts/using-the-posts-where-filter-in-wordpress

Comment: I am unclear how to use the posts_where filter for this specific case.

Comment: You wouldn't. It's not a good suggestion. Please just wait for an answer to your original question, which actually outlines the problem you're trying to solve. If you post a question about every specific suggestion, you lose the context and will get incorrect or misguided answers. If you need an _urgent_ answer, then consider hiring a professional.